# How to use a newly inserted value from another table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert, database-trigger

Assuming I have two tables `final table` and `table_1`, I want to use the the newest values from `table_1` and insert them with a trigger in the `final_table` with every `INSERT ON table_1`. When I create the triggerfunction `inserttrigger()` as shown in the example and create the trigger, I get the newest value times the number of rows in `table_1`. How to write the trigger proper that I get only the single newest record in table1?

Doing:

```
-- Create tables and inserting example values
CREATE TABLE final_table(id INTEGER, value_fin INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE table_1(id INTEGER, value INTEGER);
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(1, 200), (2,203), (3, 209);

-- Create Triggerfunction
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inserttrigger() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$

BEGIN

INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT latest.id, latest.value
FROM (SELECT NEW.id, NEW.value FROM table_1) AS latest;

RETURN NEW;                       
END;
$func$ language plpgsql;

-- Create Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER final_table_update BEFORE INSERT ON table_1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE inserttrigger() ;

--Insert example values 
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(4, 215);
```

Results in:

```
SELECT * FROM final_table

id | value_fin
 4     215
 4     215
 4     215
```

But should look like:

```
id | value_fin
 4     215
```

While:

```
CREATE TRIGGER final_table_update BEFORE INSERT ON table_1
EXECUTE PROCEDURE inserttrigger() ;
```

Results in:

```
ERROR:  record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the `VALUES()` syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inserttrigger() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO final_table VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.value);
    RETURN NEW;                       
END;
$func$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER final_table_update BEFORE INSERT ON table_1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE inserttrigger();
```

Note that you could also get the same behavior with a common-table-expression and the `returning` syntax, which avoids the need for a trigger:

```
with t1 as (
    insert into table_1(id, value_fin) values(4, 215)
    returning id, value_fin
)
insert into final_table(id, value) select id, value_fin from t1
```